# Yammer CORS error appears only for some API calls

Tags: office-365, yammer

When I request the data using yammer API sometimes I get get data while sometimes I get error saying

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/420852900347904.json' from origin 'https://blah.sharepoint.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

And for others thread ID, it is working fine like.
'https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/558918736044032.json'

Comment: Javascript origins needs to be updated with redirect url domain in app registration edit

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm using ADD token and when I make a 'https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/messages' I get all the messages but when I try to do the 'https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/about_topic/topicId' I get: *has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response*. I have the Javascript origins set with the correct URL.